# Connecting Pipes with Consumers and Producers that return different values

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I am writing a  streaming function with the pipes ecosystem, and pipes-concurrency in particular, which is based on the operational library to allow me to quickly make little program snippets which I yield commands to a server over the network or to the stdin/out of a shell command and then read back the response.  In this case it is asterisk, but could be generalized to be anything similar.

I initially wrote this with pipes in mind, but it doesn't work.  The reason the following code doesn't work is that astPipe returns a `Pipe _ _ IO a`, whereas both i and o, from pipes-concurrency both return `Consumer/Producer _ IO ()`.  I thought about having `astPipe` yield `Maybe ByteString`, and then making the output `Consumer` consume `Maybe ByteString`, but that still doesn't solve the problem of the `Producer` returning `()`.

I feel like I'm really close to a solution, but I can't quite eek it out.  You should be able to just run stack on this file to replicate.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-6.20 runghc --package pipes  --package pipes-concurrency  --package operational --package process-streaming

{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module West.Asterisk where

import System.Process.Streaming as PS
import Control.Monad.Operational as Op

import Pipes as P
import Pipes.Concurrent as PC;

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

import Control.Concurrent.Async

import GHC.IO.Exception (ExitCode)

data Version = Version String
data Channels = Channels

data AsteriskInstruction a where
    Login :: AsteriskInstruction (Maybe Version)
    CoreShowChannels :: AsteriskInstruction (Maybe Channels)

type Asterisk a = Program AsteriskInstruction a

runAsterisk :: forall a. Asterisk a -> IO a
runAsterisk m = 
  let

    runAsterisk' :: Producer B.ByteString {- TODO Response -} IO () -> Consumer B.ByteString IO () -> Asterisk a -> IO a
    runAsterisk' i o m' = runEffect $ i >-> astPipe m' >-> o
      where
        astPipe :: Asterisk a -> Pipe B.ByteString B.ByteString IO a
        astPipe k = 
          case Op.view m' of

            Return a -> return a

            Login :>>= k -> do
              yield logincmd
              resp <- await -- :: Response
              let v = undefined resp :: Maybe Version
              astPipe (k v)

            CoreShowChannels :>>= k -> do
              yield coreshowchannelscmd
              resp <- await
              let c = undefined resp :: Maybe Channels
              astPipe (k c)

  in do
    withSpawn unbounded $ \(out1, in1) -> do
        async $ asteriskManager (fromInput in1) (toOutput out1)
        runAsterisk' (fromInput in1) (toOutput out1) m 

asteriskManager :: Producer B.ByteString IO () -> Consumer B.ByteString IO () -> IO ExitCode
asteriskManager prod cons = do
  let ssh = shell "nc someserver 5038"
  execute (piped ssh) (foldOut (withConsumer cons) *> feedProducer prod *> exitCode)


logincmd, coreshowchannelscmd :: B.ByteString
logincmd = "action: login\nusername: username\nsecret: pass\nevents: off\n\n"
coreshowchannelscmd = "action: coreshowchannels\n\n"
```

The error:

```
  Blah.hs:38:45:
    Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘()’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for runAsterisk :: Asterisk a -> IO a
          at Blah.hs:33:23
    Expected type: Proxy () B.ByteString () B.ByteString IO ()
      Actual type: Pipe B.ByteString B.ByteString IO a
    Relevant bindings include
      astPipe :: Asterisk a -> Pipe B.ByteString B.ByteString IO a
        (bound at Blah.hs:41:9)
      m' :: Asterisk a (bound at Blah.hs:38:22)
      runAsterisk' :: Producer B.ByteString IO ()
                      -> Consumer B.ByteString IO () -> Asterisk a -> IO a
        (bound at Blah.hs:38:5)
      m :: Asterisk a (bound at Blah.hs:34:13)
      runAsterisk :: Asterisk a -> IO a (bound at Blah.hs:34:1)
    In the second argument of ‘(>->)’, namely ‘astPipe m'’
    In the first argument of ‘(>->)’, namely ‘i >-> astPipe m'’
```

Comment: It looks like you could just fix your type signature and it'd be better.  You have a `Consumer B.ByteString IO ()` in the type signature instead of a `Consumer B.ByteString IO a`.  The `runEffect` returns whatever your overall `Effect` returns, and you've told it that it has to be a `Consumer B.ByteString IO ()`, but that `runEffect` needs to return an `IO a`.

Comment: That doesn't work because http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-concurrency-2.0.6/docs/Pipes-Concurrent.html#v:fromInput explicitely returns `Producer' a m () `.`toOutput` is similar.  I thought about trying to convert them somehow, but I'm not sure if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Producer`s and `Consumer`s that return `()` can stop by themselves. `Producer`s and `Consumer`s that are polymorphic on their return type never stop by themselves.

To unify the return types in your case, put each one in different branches of an `Either`, using `fmap`.

```
runAsterisk' :: Producer B.ByteString IO () 
             -> Consumer B.ByteString IO () 
             -> Asterisk a 
             -> IO (Either () a)
runAsterisk' i o m' = runEffect $ fmap Left i >-> fmap Right (astPipe m') >-> fmap Left o
```

Pattern matching on the `Either` will reveal which component stopped the pipeline.

Also, you can use [`drain`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.2.0/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:drain) to transform a `Consumer a IO ()` into a consumer that never stops by itself:

```
neverStop :: Consumer a IO () -> Consumer a IO r
neverStop consumer = consumer *> drain
```

All the inputs received after the original consumer stops will be discarded.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for.  Bonus:  I can tell whether my program exited properly or if the server cuts me off unexpectedly.